# The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character using jsPDF-autotable, jspdf and smtjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

We are working on a project (serving iOS and Android in parallel) where *AngularJS* and *Ionic 1.x* still needs to be coded as re-coding to a newer version is not possible due to reasons not being worth to be mentioned here.

We now have to save the dynamic content of a table with id `tableText` using *[jsPDF-autotable](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable)* and *[jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)* to a PDF-file, which could span over more than page.

Inside the related .html-file lines like the following exist:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
    <a ng-click="getPDF()" class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-cloud-upload"></a>  
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

That way the following JavaScript-code is fired in order to attach the generated PDF-file as attachment using *[smtpjs](https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js)*:

```
$scope.getPDF = function ()
{
  var fileName = „test.pdf“;
  var emailSubject = „Title text“;
  var emailBody = „Some text“;
  var emailReceiver = „receiver@hotmail.com";
  var emailSender = „info@my.website.com“;
  var hostName =  „smtp.my.website.com“;
  var doc = new jsPDF(
  {
    orientation: 'l', 
    unit: 'mm', 
    format: [400, 210]
  });
  doc.autoTable(
    {
      html: '#tableText,
      useCss: true
    });

    var file = doc.output();
    Email.send(
      {
        Host: hostName,
        Username: emailSender,
        Password: „somePassword“,
        To: emailReceiver,
        Attachments : 
        [{
          name : fileName,
          data : file
        }], 
        From: emailSender,
        Subject: emailSubject,
        Body: emailBody
      }).then(
      message => alert(message)
    );
    //doc.save(fileName);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work as the following lines will be thrown using alert(message):

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
> character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space
> character among the padding characters

Please note:

- When sending emails without an attachment (commenting out the section
  with ‚Attachments:‘) an email is sent!
- We tried avoiding to save the PDF file first as storage for the PDF
  file is different for Android versus iOS.

Attached you will find the content of - garbage(!) - `file` for your information.[image: pdf generating problem]

What code needs to be changed/changed and how in order to have it working that a "real" PDF file will be sent as attachment?

If above lines do not make sense, we would be more than happy to see better code!

Answer (score 0):

Solution was pretty easy (I wonder how it comes that no better developer than me has found it):

```
    var blob = doc.output();
    var dataUri = "data:" + contentType + ";base64," + btoa(blob);

    Email.send(
    {
        Host: hostName,
        Username: emailSender,
        Password: "somePassword",
        To: emailReceiver,
        Attachments : 
        [{
        name : fileName,
        data : dataUri
        }], 
        From: emailSender,
        Subject: emailSubject,
        Body: emailBody
    }).then(message => alert(message)
    );
    //doc.save(fileName);
    }
```